# How to render same element multiple times in AMP?

Tags: javascript, html, amp-html

Suppose I have the following json about the user reviews:

```
{
  "reviewRating": 4,
  "comment": "this is great"
}
```

Then I use amp-list to loop through the reviews.

```
<amp-list items="." single-item>
  <template type="amp/mustache">
    <!-- How can I render 4 star images here? -->
    <span>Rating: {{reviewRating}}</span>
    <p>{{comment}}</p>
  </template>
</amp-list>
```

For the reviewRating, I want to render the same number of stars from reviewRating key/value to make a better look and feel.
How can I do this in AMP?

Comment: can you please share your rating design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible by combining `amp-bind` and `amp-list`:

```
<amp-bind-macro id="classForRating" arguments="rating, index" expression="rating >= index ? 'star-full' : (rating >= (index - 0.5) ? 'star-half' : 'star-empty')" ></amp-bind-macro>
<amp-state id="state" src="rating.json"></amp-state>
<amp-list width="136" height="24" src="rating.json" single-item items="rating" noloading>
  <template type="amp-mustache">
    <div class="star-rating" aria-label="rating: {{.}}" [aria-label]="'rating: ' + state.rating">
      <span [class]="classForRating(state.rating, 1)" class="star-empty"></span>
      <span [class]="classForRating(state.rating, 2)" class="star-empty"></span>
      <span [class]="classForRating(state.rating, 3)" class="star-empty"></span>
      <span [class]="classForRating(state.rating, 4)" class="star-empty"></span>
      <span [class]="classForRating(state.rating, 5)" class="star-empty"></span>
    </div>
  </template>
  <div class="star-rating" placeholder>
    <span class="star-empty"></span>
    <span class="star-empty"></span>
    <span class="star-empty"></span>
    <span class="star-empty"></span>
    <span class="star-empty"></span>
  </div>
</amp-list>
```

The trick is to use the same endpoint for `amp-state` and `amp-list`. The AMP runtime's response caching ensures that this will only result in a single request. AMP bindings inside an amp-list will be evaluated when the list content is being rendered. This makes it possible to set the star values (via CSS classes) using `amp-bind`.

To provide a good loading experience, I've also disabled the amp-list's default loading indicator using the `noloading` attribute. Instead I'm using a `placeholder` element showing empty stars while loading.

[Here](https://amp-demos.glitch.me/rating.html) is a working version.